# php pdo query fails to return result despite prepared statement being correct

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following php/pdo which calls a a mysql procedure which returns a filename however despite the prepared statement being correct and returning the following from a cut and pasted db query:

**db query/result**

```
>     call sp_CDRbyCustomer('Wind', 'R2X', DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 WEEK)), DATE(NOW()));
>     +------------------------------------------------------+
>     | Exported filename                                    |
>     +------------------------------------------------------+
>     | '/tmp/CDR_for_Wind_20140704-20140912_1410516460.csv' |
>     +------------------------------------------------------+
>     1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

**the php/pdo**

which should return our filename is:

```
include('db.ini');

define('DEBUG', true);
if (DEBUG ) {
        openlog("$iam", LOG_PID | LOG_ODELAY,LOG_LOCAL4);
        syslog(LOG_INFO, "START OF DEBUG LOG.");
}

/***** connect to database using db.ini for credentials *****/
try {
$dbConn =  new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $dbUser, $dbPass, array (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$structure_name = "'Wind'";
$cug_uid = "'R2X'";
$num_weeks = 10;

/**** Query - export file name ****/
$sqlQuery4filename = ("
call sp_CDRbyCustomer($structure_name, $cug_uid, DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $num_weeks WEEK)), DATE(NOW()))
");
$sqlQuery4filename = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $sqlQuery4filename );

    debug("01: sqlQueryfile string is '" . $sqlQuery4filename . "'");
    $stmnt = $dbConn->prepare($sqlQuery4filename);
    debug($stmnt);
    $stmnt->execute();
    $stmnt->closeCursor();
    $filename = $stmnt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $filename = $filename['Exported filename'];
    debug("01: filename string is '" . $filename . "'");

function debug($debug) {
if(!DEBUG) return;

print '
<div class="debug">
';
print_r($debug);
print '
</div><!-- end of debug -->
';
}
```

However I only ever get an empty string returned.

I have had this working, but after subversioning it I ended up with the wrong version and can no longer get it to work, anybody give me any clues to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: To make this clearer, the sql procedure call above is 'cut' and 'pasted' from the result of 'debug($stmnt);'. We then run '$stmnt->execute();' and '$stmnt->closeCursor();' but '$stmnt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);' returns empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much debugging and many different coding attempts I eventually retrieved teh required result.

I tried numerous attempts to use binParam but the returned result would always be a null string.

I had changed to mysql procedure to output the required filename so the mysql command  SELECT @filename would provide the desired result.

I then retrieved this value with the following:

```
   /**** Query - export file name ****/
   $sql = 'call sp_CDRbyCustomer( \'' . $structure_name . '\', \'' . $cug_uid . '\', DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ' . $num_weeks . ' WEEK)), DATE(NOW()),  @filename )';

    $stmnt = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
    debug($stmnt);
    $stmnt->execute();
    $stmnt->closeCursor();
    $filename_result = $dbConn->query("select @filename")->fetch();
    $filename = $filename_result['@filename'];
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this but it does produce the result I desire :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly debug this:

1. See what the exact SQL command is you execute (I can't tell from your question).
2. Test the command against the database, for instance with PHPmyAdmin.
3. Show what the `fetch()` result is, before you access it as an array.

If you follow the PHP execution trial from the beginning to the end, you should be able to work out where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the output parameter. See Example #4 in the docs http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_returns_string(?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000); 

// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();

print "procedure returned $return_value\n";
?>
```